# When I try to check if email exists jQuery doesn't give the error?

Tags: php, jquery, email

I'm trying to check if email exists or not in database but when i do this, jQuery doesn't show the message that already existed.

The error is at the if statment "if(cemail == 1)"  just in that if.

Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#sub").submit(function() {

            if($("#username").val()==""||$("#email").val()=="") {
                $("#warn2").hide(36000);
                $("#loading").css("display:inline");
                $("#loading").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' width='1%' height='3%' /> A carregar...");
                $("#loading").fadeIn(200);
                $("#loading").fadeOut(200);
                $("#warn2").css("display:none");
                $("#warn2").html("Por favor escreve o teu nome e/ou email!<br />");
                $("#warn2").hide(36000);
                $("#warn2").fadeIn(1000);                   
                $("#warn2").css("display:inline");
                $("#warn2").fadeOut(7000);

            }

            else {                                         


                var s = $("#sub").serializeArray();
                $.ajax({

                    success: function(cemail) {

                            if(cemail == 1) {
                            $.ajax ({ url: "check-email.php", method: "POST", data: "" });  
                            $("#warn2").hide(36000);
                            $("#loading").css("display:inline");
                            $("#loading").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' width='1%' height='3%' /> A carregar...");
                            $("#loading").fadeIn(200);
                            $("#loading").fadeOut(200);
                            $("#warn2").css("display:none");
                            $("#warn2").html("Esse E-mail j&aacute; se encontra na nossa base de dados!<br />");
                            $("#warn2").hide(36000);
                            $("#warn2").fadeIn(1000);                   
                            $("#warn2").css("display:inline");
                            $("#warn2").fadeOut(7000);
                        } else {
                var email = $("#email").val();
                                  if(isValid(email)==false){
                    $("#warn2").hide(36000);
                    $("#loading").css("display:inline");
                    $("#loading").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' width='1%' height='3%' /> A carregar...");
                    $("#loading").fadeIn(200);
                    $("#loading").fadeOut(200);
                    $("#warn2").css("display:none");
                    $("#warn2").html("Por favor introduza um e-mail v&aacute;lido!<br />");
                    $("#warn2").hide(36000);
                    $("#warn2").fadeIn(1000);                   
                    $("#warn2").css("display:inline");
                    $("#warn2").fadeOut(7000);
                    $.ajax ({ url: "", method: "POST", data: "" });
                }
                     else {

                            $("#success").css("display:none");              
                            $("#success").hide(36000);
                            $("#loading").css("display:inline");
                            $("#loading").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' width='1%' height='3%' /> A carregar...");
                            $("#loading").fadeIn(200);
                            $("#loading").fadeOut(200);
                            $("#success").css("display:none");
                            $("#success").html("A tua subscri&ccedil;&atilde;o foi efectuada com successo!");
                            $("#success").hide(36000);
                            $("#success").fadeIn(1000);                 
                            $("#success").css("display:inline");
                            $("#success").fadeOut(7000);
                            $.ajax ({ url: "subscribe.php",
                            method: "POST",
                            data: s,});
                            $("#username").val("");
                            $("#email").val("");
                            return true;
                        }

                 }

            }


            });


 function isValid(email) {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        if(!regex.test(email)) {
           return false;
        }else{
           return true;
        }
      }
            }
        return false;




    });

        $("#MGa").click(function() {

            $("#hidGames").css("display: inline");
            $("#hidGames").fadeToggle(1000);


            return false;
        });

        $("#MGa").mouseover(function() {

            $("#arrow").html('<img src="images/arrow_wbm_hover.png" width="1%" height="1%" />');


        });

        $("#MGa").mouseout(function() {

            $("#arrow").html('<img src="images/arrow.png" width="1%" height="1%" />');


        });

        $("#eqp_tec").click(function() {

            $("eqpTec").css("display: inline");
            $("#eqpTec").fadeToggle(1000);

            return false;

        });


        $("#arrow").html('<img src="images/arrow.png" width="1%" height="1%" />');

    });
</script>
```

and here is the php page (check-email.php):

```
<?php

include("db.php");

$email = $_POST['email'];


$cemail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subs WHERE email='$email'");

$rows = mysql_num_rows($cemail);

if($rows==1) {
    echo "User in database";
} else {
    // whatever
}

?>
```

Can you try fix me this error ? I really need it. 
If this error continues it will give me headaches, more than I am now. Help me fix this error.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Several problems here (not the least of which is that you have some seriously overwrought code)

First, you have two `ajax` function calls, one wrapping the other.

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(cemail) {
        if(cemail == 1) {
```

I'm not even sure what the first one would do since it doesn't specify a URL. That looks to be a major problem but I have no idea what happens if you call JQ AJAX without a URL. You really need to read the [jQuery AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) here and possibly remove that first `ajax` call.

Second, you're repeating yourself. **A lot.** A core principle of coding is

> DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself

That's what functions are for. They do your repetition for you. That makes your code more legible. So here's a sample function you need to add.

```
function showError(error) {
    $("#warn2").hide(36000);
    $("#loading").css("display:inline");
    $("#loading").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' width='1%' height='3%' /> A carregar...");
    $("#loading").fadeIn(200);
    $("#loading").fadeOut(200);
    $("#warn2").css("display:none");
    $("#warn2").html(error);
    $("#warn2").hide(36000);
    $("#warn2").fadeIn(1000);                   
    $("#warn2").css("display:inline");
    $("#warn2").fadeOut(7000);
}
```

Third, you're using [mysql_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Click that link and read the red box. You need to stop using those functions because they will likely be removed from PHP.

Fourth, your PHP is open to SQL injection. Here's a [handy page](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) that tells you how to be secure.